# how to get Json value from json array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

i need to get my country name from Json Array but when i tried the code its not showing anything..
this is the Json output

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "status": "OK",
  "status_message": "Success",
  "country_details": [
    {
      "country_code": "AF",
      "country_name": "Afghanistan",
      "country_iso": "AFG",
      "country_flag": "http://..../img/countryflags/128x128/af.png",
      "calling_code": "93",
      "fancier_count": 2
    },
```

here i want only `country_name` but when i tried this code..its not showing me anything..
here is my code:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = "";
            try {
                list.add("Select Country");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                String data = (URLEncoder.encode("dest", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("destination", "UTF-8"));
                URLConnection conn = new URL("http://.../api/getCountries").openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line = rd.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    wr.close();
                    rd.close();
                    //return Boolean.valueOf(true);
                } else {
                    result += line;
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            //parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // add interviewee name to arraylist


                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("country_name"));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PMRegisterActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Fetching data", true, false);
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

i know i am missing something in this ...but not getting what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change JSON parse as below

```
           try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("country_details");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // add interviewee name to arraylist


                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("country_name"));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

//parse json data

```
         try {
        JSONObject resultJsonObject=new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray country_detailsJsonArray=resultJsonObject.getJSONArray("country_details");
        for (int i=0;i<country_detailsJsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject countryONJ=country_detailsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String country_name=countryONJ.getString("country_name");
            Log.d("country_name","="+country_name);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
  try {
      JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
      JSONArray jsArray= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("country_details");
      for (int i = 0; i < jsArray.length(); i++) 
      {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);

        list.add(jsonObject.getString("country_name"));
      }
    } catch (JSONException e) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `result` variable would have above `Json`

change parsing Json part to this

```
 try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("country_details")
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // add interviewee name to arraylist


                list.add(jsonObject.getString("country_name"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

/*For my project I used this and it work perfectly*/

```
JSONArray item = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                for(int i=0;i<item.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = item.getJSONObject(i);

                    String date = jsonObject.getString("webPublicationDate");
                    String title= jsonObject.getString("webTitle");
                    String preview = jsonObject.getString("webUrl");
                    String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
}
```